# MKMapView in ios6 and OpenGL rendering

Tags: opengl-es, ios6, maps, mkmapview, layer

Got an app running an OpenGL layer on top of a `MKMapView`. This worked like a charm up until iOS 6 and Apple Maps...

The problem with iOS 6 / Apple Maps is that the performance is terrible, resulting in 3d objects jumping around when you pan / zoom the map. I'm guessing the issue is due to `MKMapView` now using OpenGL to render the map, but I am stumped as to how to make it work...

The iOS 5 / Google Maps version uses a regular `CADisplayLink` for rendering, but that proved horribly laggy with Apple Maps.

I then tried moving the rendering to a `MKOverlay` and calling my "draw frame" from there, which improved performance slightly but it was still pretty shitty compared to the iOS 5 / Google Maps version.

I ended up adding a Pan / Pinch gesture recognizer on the `MKMapView` and manually calling "draw frame" every time the map is panned / pinched. This works slightly better than the overlay but is still a long way from performance on iOS 5 / Google Maps.

It is however extremely frustrating having the app run at 45-50 fps on an iPhone 4S with iOS 5, and the same app runs at 15-20 fps on an iPhone 5 with iOS 6 ...

I've tried doing the rendering on background threads, high priority threads, low priority threads, delaying it, calling it asynchronously, I just can't get anywhere close to the performance on iOS 5 :(

Any ideas or suggestions how to happily combine the OpenGL rendering from `MKMapView` in iOS 6 with custom OpenGL rendering calls?

Comment: I have same problem with very similar case. Report to Apple as bug and pray?

Comment: Also no answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919677/performance-issues-with-mapkit-on-ios6